# Can Aptana do code folding?

Tags: aptana, code-folding

I would like to code folding in aptana 2 but I cannot figure out how to do it. How do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean these things?

[image]

Go to

```
Window > Preferences
```

Type in <del>`code`</del> `folding` (my bad) into the search box, then change the preferences.

Comment: Yes that is what I want, but when I type in code folding it comes up with nothing at all

Comment: @chromedude Hmmm... that can't be right - as far as I can tell, it's available by default in all interfaces - script, PHP, HTML and CSS. What OS are you using it on?

Comment: @chromedude It's folding - my mistake, sorry.

Comment: @Yi Jiang Got it thanks. hmm... does aptana only fold comments and functions? I thought it would fold ifs, loops, and try-catchs too?

Comment: @chromedude. Apparently not, you'll have to look through it to be sure. I've never really had much use for this anyway.

Comment: @Yi Jiang ok, Thanks anyway. I find it useful because then if you have a bunch of if statements inside each other it can make it slightly less confusing to collapse the ones you are not working on.